# Open native map and then back to application phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary, cordova, back

I'm facing a problem, I'm developing a hybrid application using phonegap and the customer wants the possibility to open the native map (Apple map for iOS and Google Map for Android) with a marker and then back to the application when finished. On android It's OK, the back button is already implemented, however my problem is for iOS. I already developed a little plugin to open the native map and place a marker with the following code :

```
CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
NSNumber * latN = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
NSNumber * lonN = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:1];
double lat = [latN doubleValue];
double lon = [lonN doubleValue];

CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon);

MKPlacemark *myPlacemark = [[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:myCoordinate       addressDictionary:nil]autorelease];

MKMapItem *mapItem = [[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:myPlacemark]autorelease];
mapItem.name = @"My car";
[mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];


if (latN != nil && lonN != nil) {
pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"ok"];
} else {
pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];
}

[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
```

Is there a way to perform this on iOS ?
Thanks in advance,
Med.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come back with a solution that I used in my case, after a lot of research I found that the only way to do it was to use the mapKit framework.
So I simply used cordova MapKit plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/MapKit) with some modifications because this version is not necessary up to date.
I setup a view with the map view and a toolbar with a back button on the top, so we can access the native map and then back to the application easily.
Med.